# Why are there questions with an accepted answer in the Close Vote review queue?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review

When doing my duty reviewing the Close Vote queue, I see many questions that should have been closed initially but which now have an accepted answer, still aren't closed and are in the "Close Vote" review queue.

I know that some of those questions, especially among the obvious duplicates, should probably never have received answers but what's the point in closing them now after the answer has been accepted ?

Does it achieve something ? Is that a first step for deletion ? Is there another impact than just putting "[Closed]" in their title ? Or is this just an almost useless task on questions we could just forget ?

*Note that my question isn't, now, a feature request (i.e. "Please remove questions with accepted answer from the Close Vote review queue ?") but a request for explanation or opinion.*

Answer (score 3):

It just happens because someone is fast enough to post an answer before the question is closed. Think about the following situation:

1. I post a very basic question which should be closed for some reason, e.g. "Please show me how to sort an array!"
2. Most comments are of course something like "dude, what have you tried?", "show us some effort", "try something yourself before asking" and so on. The first close vote is casted.
3. Someone who either wants some rep, or is just kind enough and has free time posts a detailed example of bubble sort.
4. The final close vote is cast.
5. The OP finds the solution acceptable, and ticks the answer.

There you go, a closed question with an accepted answer.

Now, about the point of closing them. We assume that the closed questions *need to be closed*. Some of them are bad, some of them are off-topic, some are dups. In fact, they should not have received answers, and most users ignore such qestions. But some people still answer those, and there's nothing bad in it really. We all have free will, and if someone wants to give an answer to a duplicate, or to a question with no research effort shown, no one can stop them from doing it.

**Update:**

Ok, seems that I misunderstood you a little. I thought you were asking about why do people answer those ready-to-close questions, but apparently you're asking the opposite thing: why close a question if answers are given already.

If the question falls under some closing criteria, it needs to be closed. Once again, you shouldn't be confused about the answers given. If you see a question which is *clearly a duplicate*, it should be closed as a duplicate. Well ok, someone might have answered it again. But it's not the presence or absence of answers/response that is the reason for closing, it's the fact that the question is a duplicate/offtopic/whatsoever, and this reason does not change depending on answers given.